# C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - How to replace a formula with its value?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to replace formulas on column D with their values.

eg. currently D1 = C1 / 2

If C1 = 10, I want D1 to be 5

I need to do this because I need to delete the column C.

I tried changing the format to Text like below but it doesn't seem to replace formulas with their values

```
  Excel.Style style = workbook.Styles.Add("styleText", Missing.Value);
  style.NumberFormat = "@";

  Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range("D1", Missing.Value);
  range.Style = style;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a macro in VBA that does what you need... It's VB code but I dont think woould be a problem to translate it in C#

```
Sub ValuesOnly()
    Dim rRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the formulas", Title:="VALUES ONLY", Type:=8)
    If rRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    rRange = rRange.Value
End Sub
```

Another way to do it is to simply mimic the command Paste Special -> Values. I have just recorded a macro that does it (C5 in my sample is a cell that contains a function)

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand... What does the InputBox return? And I don't think rRange = rRange.Value will ever work in C#.

Comment: The InputBox will simply return a Range object. The user can write there something like `C3`, `C3:D4` and so on... Anyway the second sample show you how to mimic the Paste Special command. Why do you think that will not work with c#?

Comment: Oh thanks for creating that macro for me... Sorry I have no idea how to translate it to C#. The objects seem to be very different.

Comment: I got it I got it! Thanks a lot Lorenzo!

    private static void ReplaceFormulasWithValues(ref Excel.Worksheet sheet, char column)
    {
      Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range(column + "1", Missing.Value).EntireColumn;
      range.Copy(Missing.Value);
      range.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
    }

Comment: Good to know that helped! I have also found another way to do it and edited your answer. Pleae have a look at it and choose the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

How do you format a comment??

Here is the solution I got, thanks to Lorenzo

```
private static void ReplaceFormulasWithValues(ref Excel.Worksheet sheet, char column)
{
  Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range(column + "1", Missing.Value).EntireColumn;
  range.Copy(Missing.Value);
  range.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
}
```

This is another way to do it (C1 contains a formula, the result is placed in D1)

```
static void Main( string[] args ) {
    string fileName = @"D:\devprj\Temp\TempProject\bin\Debug\Cartel1.xlsx";
    Application ac = new Application();
    Workbook wb = ac.Workbooks.Open( fileName );
    Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];

    Range rangeOrigin = ws.get_Range( "C1" );
    Range rangeDestination = ws.get_Range( "D1" );
    rangeDestination.Value = rangeOrigin.Value2;

    wb.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change the display style, because that doesn't change the content of the cell.  When you're doing this manually in Excel you need to copy the column and then choose Paste Special -> Values to paste the values rather than the formulae.  I imagine there's a programatic way to do the same operation.